# Adding Javascript Functions to Load Google Maps C# WPF

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to integrate Google Maps into a WebBrowserControl in my C# WPF program. The map loads in the control and centers on the correct latitude and longitude, however I am having a couple of errors. First of all, the map loads and after a couple of seconds I get an error box appear;

[image]

Secondly, when I am trying to add a marker on the location of the latitude and longitude, I get an error even before the map loads at all. Here is my code so far;

```
mapWebBrowser.NavigateToString(@"<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"" xmlns:v=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"">
                                <head>
                                <meta http - equiv = ""X-UA-Compatible"" content = ""IE=edge""/>
                                <meta name = ""viewport"" content = ""initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no""/>
                                <script type = ""text/javascript""
                                src = ""http://maps.google.com.mx/maps/api/js?sensor=true&language=""es"" ></script>
                                <script src = 'http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js'>
                                </script><script type = ""text/javascript"">
                                    function initialize() {
                                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(" + latitude + ", " + longitude + @");
                                        var myOptions = {
                                            zoom: 16,
                                            center: latlng,
                                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                        };
                                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(""map_canvas""), myOptions);
                                    }
                                    function addMarker( Lat, Long) {   
                                        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Long);            
                                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            position:   latLng,
                                            draggable:  false,
                                            animation:  google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                                        });
                                        markers.push(marker);
                                        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers)
                                    }
                                </script>
                                </head>
                                <body onload = ""initialize()"" >
                                    <div id=""map_canvas"" style=""width:100%; height:100%""></div>
                                </body>
                                </html>");
```

This is the function I am attempting to use to add a marker onto the map;

```
function addMarker( Lat, Long) {   
         var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Long);            
         marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position:   latLng,
                  draggable:  false,
                  animation:  google.maps.Animation.DROP,
         });
         markers.push(marker);
         var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers)
}
```

Which I call in C#;

`mapWebBrowser.InvokeScript("addMarker", new object[] { latitude, longitude } );`

Unfortunately as I stated before both methods are causing issues.

Comment: There are some typing mistakes, like: "<script src = 'http://..." -> I think it must be in double-quotes. Or: "animation:  google.maps.Animation.DROP, -> at the last item "," is not allowed. Follow Stoynev advise and develope in HTML/JS and then change the working code to that what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there was a change in Google's APIs back in June and they now require authentication for google maps. I don't see your API key being supplied anywhere. I would suggest you try  your HTML/javascript in the browser or where you can sniff the requests and the responses and see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you still can't solve your problem. You may use **Script Errors Suppressed** too. Then this window will disappear.

```
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```